# How can I disable waiting room in Google Meets created with calendar api?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

In the Google Calendar api there's the ability to request that a conferencing link be created when an event is created.

My current setup is that I have an account that is creating google calendar events whenever someone schedules a meeting on my app. The problem is that when someone outside of my organization tries to join the meeting it says "ask to join" which isn't possible since nobody from my organization will be in the meeing. Are there are parameters to let me turn off the waiting room feature or at least have a list of approved emails that are allowed to enter the meeting. The request body looks like this right now:

```
{
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2020-08-30T05:27:35.206Z"
  },
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2020-08-29T05:27:35.206Z"
  },
  "conferenceData": {
    "createRequest": {
      "conferenceSolutionKey": {
        "type": "hangoutsMeet"
      },
      "requestId": "12345"
    }
  },
  "summary": "Test event with meets 2",
  "attendees": [
    {
      "email": "****@gmail.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

The attendee I added still has to request to join the meeting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### This appears to be a bug!

I have taken the liberty of reporting this on Google's Issue Tracker for you, detailing the behaviour:

- [User from outside of G Suite domain required to ask to join a Meeting from a Calendar event they are invited to](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/166749877)

You can hit the ☆ next to the issue number in the top left on the page which lets Google know more people are encountering this and so it is more likely to be seen to faster.